# Python RegEx subbing [" "]

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggeling with a bit of a problem here. I need to migrate a wiki and it's internal links. These links are in many different formats, one of which is: ["link"]

i tried this:

```
m = re.search(r'\[\"(\w+\s\w+)\"\]',s)

if m:
    print m.group(1)
    m2 = re.sub(r'\[\"(?:[^\]|]*\|)?([^\]|]*)\"\]', r'\1', s)
    return m2
```

But that did not work... Any ideas on how to do this with regex the correct way?

**EDIT**

It also needs to ignore any spaces in the link. So for example ["this is a test"] has to work as well

Comment: In what way did it "not work"?

Comment: "But that did not work". What does this mean? Did you get an exception (which one? what was the traceback?) Did you get an unexpected result (what was the expected result? what you got instead?) Did the program crash? Without further information we cannot say anything.

Comment: I just realized that the re.sub does work, but i also need to have the search in there. That part does not work

Comment: I just get a None back. Nothing else even though i expect the raw link to return

Comment: @WouterMellema You do not need the search at all. `re.sub` will already search the whole string and replace all the occurrences it finds.

Comment: I know, but i need the program to either give me the raw link back OR a None. this is because I check every word in the program using this and I only want the links to come through

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression has the problem that you are expecting a word (`\w+`), some whitespace (`\s`), and another word. So you won’t get single words, or longer links (e.g. `this is a test`). Instead, you probably want to look for a word followed by another word that is separated by whitespace; and that repeatedly: `(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)`.

But you could also just match anything that isn’t a quotation character since your links have to end with them:

```
s = 'Some ["text"] with ["lots of links"] as an ["example"] for a ["regular expression"] that ["finds them all"].'
>>> re.findall('\["([^"]+)"\]', s)
['text', 'lots of links', 'example', 'regular expression', 'finds them all']
```